# Drupal 8 - Ajax modal not working from dynamically created links

Tags: ajax, modal-dialog, drupal-8

I have added link in my website like bellow

```
<a href="/product/info/100" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal">Info</a>
```

This is working if it is loaded at the time of page load.
But the issue is, I need to create the links when user chooses some option . I have created new link like this during some customer action after page load.But the modal not showing from the newly created links.

Comment: See also: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2997668

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the bellow code after creating the elements solve the issue

```
$('.use-ajax').click(function(e){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    Drupal.ajax({url: url}).execute();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue and fixed by re-binding the ajax event for dynamicly generated elements:

```
Drupal.ajax.bindAjaxLinks(document.body)
```

Details can be found in source code:

```
core\misc\ajax.js -> Drupal.ajax.bindAjaxLinks
```

Answer (score 0):

```
When html is loaded by ajax and drupal modal popup does not work.
For me below code worked.

HTML code:
    <button class="use-ajax" onclick="function_name("/url") ></button>

Jquery code
    function function_name(url){   
      Drupal.ajax({url: url}).execute();  
    }
```